# Custom component can't included using CkEditor button in mura cms

Tags: mura

I Create a custom component and try to add my custom component in page but when I click on CKEditor button to add the component it shows the pop-up then I select the component and try to add but it cannot add component also when I add component using the mura tags than it adds the component.

```
[m]$.dspObject('component', 'EE5C8CBF-4980-48FD-AC8870B2594495E2')[/m]
```

Above code include mura tags then it destroyed my UI, please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Sounds like you may have an issue within your component that is throwing an error. Try taking code/content out of your component and see if it will allow you to attach it to the page. Assuming that works, start adding back the content a little at a time to see at what point it breaks. Then fix that issue.

Comment: @Miguel-F simply I create the mura cms component and only add three custom field and try to add in the content page but it cannot be added and if I used mura tag then it includes but it also binds my Html with mura Html tags with extra div element